# How to send all file names from `git diff` in output in github action

Tags: github-actions

```
name: Git diff files changed 
jobs:
  if-file-changed:
    name: Check if files changed
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 # fetch all history of all branches


      - name: Get files changed when pr is created/updated
        # compare source branch with target branch in Pull request
        if: github.event_name=='pull_request'
        id: files_changed_on_pr
        run: |
          git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD origin/${{github.base_ref}}
          all_changed_files=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only origin/${{github.head_ref}} origin/${{github.base_ref}})
          echo "::set-output name=all_changed_files::$all_changed_files"
          echo  all_changed_files = $all_changed_files

      - name: Get output
        id: get_output
        run: |
          all_changed_files=${{ steps.files_changed_on_pr.outputs.all_changed_files }}
          echo $all_changed_files
```

- I see 4 files in job id `files_changed_on_pr`
  Output looks like following:

> all_changed_files = .github/workflows/files_changed.yaml
> .github/workflows/load_seed_data.yaml
> .github/workflows/miscellaneous_test.yaml
> .github/workflows/on_pr_dev.yaml

- I only see 1 file in job id `get_output`

> .github/workflows/files_changed.yaml

Is there some kind of JSON conversion I need to do before sending those files as output?